# Move Focus to Server Side Validator

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with multiple CustomValidators and I want the focus to be brought to the offending validator when there is an error.  I know this is possible with client side validation, but is it possible with server side?

Additionally, the CustomValidators are located in different parts of the page so I can't simply scroll the page to one general location when there is any validation failure.

I have tried:
  SetFocusOnError
  CustomValidator.Focus() immediately after validation, after the button click, and in Page.PreRender()

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a colleague, I have a solution to this question.  It's so simple I wish I had come up with it!  Just inject javascript when the validator fails and that javascript will be executed on postback.

```
Private Sub CustomValidator_ServerValidate(ByVal source as Object, ByVal args as System.Web.UI.WebControls.ServerValidateEventArgs) Handles CustomValidator.ServerValidate
    If someCondition Then
        args.IsValid = True
    Else
        args.IsValid = False
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.GetType(), "JumpToValidator", "jumpToValidator(validatorId);", True)
    End If
End Sub`
```

where jumpToValidator(validatorId) is a javascript function that scrolls to the element passed in as an argument.